# On-screen keyboard for touch display

Tags: keyboard, input-device

I'm in hour 4 of searching for an on screen keyboard to use with an Asus eeetop all in one touch screen computer.  One feature I'd like is the ability to hide and view the keyboard easily and intuitively.

I have to assume the end use of these computers will be novice at best, as they will be retail kiosks, and the keyboard used for searching inventory.

I'm not at all tied down to XP as the operating system.

So, if you've come across a great touch screen keyboard for Windows XP *OR* Ubuntu, please make a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using Windows 7 on my Lenovo s10-3t, and it has 2 great on-screen keyboards to choose from:

The tablet input panel (that also recognizes handwriting):
[image: tablet input panel]

And the larger on-screen keyboard (osk.exe):
[image: osk]

Another alternative is [Ilium's Inscribe](http://www.iliumsoft.com/site/fp/inscribe.php), which is free and very configurable.

There are various other alternatives (just Google "on screen keyboard") but they are not free (although neither is Windows 7 :))

Comment: How does this handle text input? Does the keyboard auto popup and hide based on field focus like in iOS and Android?

Comment: Yes. You could control them via settings, but basically the keyboard is there for you anytime text editing is needed

Answer (score 1):

Just go to `run` and type in `OSK`, this is the built in Windows on screen keyboard.

It is in every edition of Windows from XP and up.
[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion

It seems to have only one size setting and at 1600x900 resolution the keys are very small to type on.

Comment: use another of Microsofts usability programs, the `screen magnifier`. It can be found by hitting win+u. That would make it visible

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to shell out $100 for Windows 7, they have some great touchscreen support.

**Update**: You may also want to check out [this](http://www.comfort-software.com/on-screen-keyboard.html) software. It seems useful.