# Desktop OS for touch screen PC

Tags: touchscreen, on-screen-keyboard

I am looking for an OS that will work on a touch screen display. This is for a kiosk in a customer's store. This could be rolled out to as many as 500 stores and needs to be solid and maintainable.

The OS only has to display a web browser in Full Screen mode and run a few web applications.

The one feature that makes or breaks my decision is how typing into text fields is handled. When a text field gets focus (user touches field) an on-screen keyboard needs to appear. When the field looses focus (user touches something else) the keyboard needs to go away.

I found his thread that suggests Windows 7 but does specify how the on-screen keyboard is opened or closed. [On-screen keyboard for touch display](https://superuser.com/questions/181375/on-screen-keyboard-for-touch-display)

So far I have had a hard time finding concrete information online. It appears that This will not work on Windows 7 or a Linux distribution (please correct me if I am wrong).

I am not sure how I feel about being left with only beta versions of x86 ports of Android or the beta version of Windows 8 (Metro) but those are looking like they might be my only options.

Does anyone have additional information? Has anyone accomplished a solution like this?

**UPDATE** 
I forgot that it has been already been decided, by management, that we will be using a 32" touch display for the kiosk.

Comment: Windows 7 fully supports the on-screen keyboard, and you can have it enabled by default if you have a touchscreen-compatible display.

Comment: @Breakthrough, does this mean it will popup when a field gains focus and hide when it looses focus? This needs to be dead simple. It is for a store kiosk that will have a huge range of people using it.

Comment: I believe it does, yes.  I was at a restaurant the other day with a Windows 7 touch-screen at my table, and every input field I "clicked" brought up the OSK.

Comment: @Breakthrough, if it does that will be great. We are ordering the equipment to set up a demi unit and test out OSs. I'll give Windows 7 a try first. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you feel about using iOS on iPads? You can even use the [Apple Configurator](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12&ls=1)
 to disable the home button. You could use something like OpenDNS (or some sort of proxy server) to whitelist only certain websites, or (preferably) create a custom app that essentially gives you nothing but a full screen web view.

This is exactly what Apple has done in their retail stores with their [Smart Signs](http://news.cnet.com/2300-27076_3-10007858.html). They've disabled the home button and launch the iPad into what is essentially a full screen web view. All content you see on the Smart Signs is just HTML.

Comment: Thanks Liam. I left out a key part to my question. It has been decided already, by my bosses, that it will be a 32" touch display.